# --disable-web-security for all browsers

Tags: java, javascript, html, security, cross-browser

I write application with XMLHttpRequest authorization on site framesocket.com. Application work well, but only in Google Chrome with parametr --disable-web-security. Any ideas how to resolve this problem(in Java, javascript, html) for its run in Opera, Mozilla and etc?

```
Code:
    function uploadNext() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData();
            var file = document.getElementById('files').files[filesUploaded];
            fd.append('key', '*********);
            fd.append('secret', '************');
            fd.append('sig', hex_md5('***********'));
            fd.append('media', file);
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", onUploadProgress, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("load", onUploadComplete, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("error", onUploadFailed, false);
            debug('uploading ' + file.name);
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.framesocket.com/api/media/upload.php', true);
            xhr.send(fd);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the same-origin policy will prevent this code from running this code from another domain.

If your code is not hosted by that domain and they don't send CORS-header. There is no way to connect  to that host with an ajax request.

You may write  "real" form and make a post to an iframe with that target. But not within an async ajax request.

Comment: Do you meen I must create iframe and post data from it?